# How to use emacs projectile-find-file without "full path"?

Tags: emacs, projectile

I'm new to Emacs, so recently I faced the problem of "how to quickly find and open a file in emacs?" (something like Go-to in sublime/atom, Cmd-P). As a solution I'm using projectile package, but its behaviour is slightly different in the following scenario. If I want to narrow down my search providing only parts of the path, it wont be able to find the file I'm looking for. Eg.

Given the following file on my project:

`my-project/lib/something/bananas`

on emacs, I run `M-x projectile-find-file` or `C-c p f`, how could I find the above file providing only `lib` and `bananas`?

If i type `bananas`(only) I can find the file, what I'm looking for is a way of narrow the search as I might have multiple files named `bananas`

I tried something like `lib/*/bananas` but didn't work.

Basically the behaviour that I'm trying to achieve is equivalent to this:

[atom example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwxzMl7pfpTAUG9WTWJ1RVFlT3M/view) (link to example as unfortunately I don't have reputation(points) enough to upload a photo here)

Comment: What you are describing is generally called "fuzzy finding" or "flex matching".  There are plenty of packages out there that provide this feature, but emacs won't do this out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it works with

```
M-x projectile-find-file or C-c p f
```

Just separate search tags with space, in your example:

```
lib bananas
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the packages that you can use for this is [helm-projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile).

Answer (score 0):

I use `ido-ubiquitious` for this (along with `(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)`).  It makes pretty much any completion use `ido`, and thus gives you fuzzy matching.  You can use `M-SPC` to incrementally narrow your search, e.g. `C-c p f l i b M-SPC b a n a n a s M-SPC`.  The matching is still fuzzy, so it doesn't matter if you narrow by "bananas" or "lib" first.